# Clock on the razor page in Blazor 8

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, clock, .net-8.0

Clock razor page

```cs
<h1>Current</h1>
<div id="clock"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js">
<script>
        function updateClock() {
            var now = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
            document.getElementById('clock').innerText = now;
        }

        updateClock();

        setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
</script>
```

procram.cs : grobal rendering mode setting for SSR

```cs
app.MapRazorComponents<App>()
    .AddInteractiveServerRenderMode();
```

And installed, moment.js library from Nuget.

But the clock only works after refeshing manually.

I tried

```cs
    [Inject]
    private IJSRuntime JSRuntime { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("setInterval");
    }
```

or

```cs
app.MapRazorComponents<App>()
    .AddAdditionalAssemblies();
```

But nothing changed.

How can I make it work automatically?

Comment: Have you checked the browser log? Does the click event fired? Are there any error you are getting there?

Comment: You are trying to use Blazor without learning Blazor.  Go through the docs or basic tutorials, and you'll see that you should not declare scripts in components.  Second, C# has timers, so why you are trying to import a .js script to do that is a little sus.

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 you are right, I need to learn more and have to read docs in depth. I just a newbie on Blazor who jump into with Udemy Video (mostly it covers only Blazor (Net6) or recently MVC Net 8, that's all. I am being in a little confusion with blazor 8 rendermode&prerendering. Thanks.

Comment: There is absolutely no reason to use java for this. You will learn this with time.

Comment: A JavaScript clock would make a lot of sense on a SSR (static serverside rendering) page. Keeping a SignalR circuit open would be costly for such a small task.

Comment: @sayditto not trying to be snarky, btw. There are some EXTREMELY good resources available, and JS interop is covered by most of them.  Here's one: https://blazor-university.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Clock on the razor page in Blazor 8 . But nothing changed.
>
> How can I make it work automatically?

Well, based on your description and shared code snippet it seems that you are trying to make a clock which would be showing `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss`. So I not sure why you are using javascript for that!, we actually don't need scripting.

In order make a clock,  all we need is a [`OnTimerTick`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer.interval?view=net-8.0) that should update with a [interval](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer.interval?view=net-8.0) of second, that's it.

So, we need a time tick funtion /method that would update the clock in every second, you are done.

Let's have a look how we could refactor your code without JavaScript. If there's any specific requirement for script that's the another story. But you could do as following:

```
@page "/clock"
@implements IDisposable

<div id="clock"><h1>Clock:@currentDateTime </h1></div>

@code {
    private string currentDateTime = "";
    private System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        /*
            I am updating every second
         */
        timer.Interval = 1000; 
        timer.Elapsed += OnTimerTick;
        timer.Start();
        await UpdateClock();
    }

    private async Task UpdateClock()
    {
        currentDateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
    }

    private void OnTimerTick(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        InvokeAsync(UpdateClock);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        timer.Stop();
        timer.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Output:

[image]

[image]

**Note:** This is one of the way, but if you want to implement using Javascript, please check your browser console if there is any error. But for this clock I don't think that's mandatory. In addition, please [refer to this official document for more sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer.interval?view=net-8.0).

Comment: You are so amazing in this short time, thank you so much. I've been looking into Javascript all along because I vaguely thought that C# code would be a huge drain on the server's resources. Thanks to you, I've had a great learning experience.

Comment: If you can add some more, is this code really compatible with javascript in performance?

Comment: Of course its performant, this is why blazor comes in, you could write JS using server language. It generates the JS Dom for you, if you debug you could see that in inspect element.